# ScrollMagic media queries?

Tags: javascript, parallax, gsap, scrollmagic

I am using the ScrollMagic plugin found [here](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic).  I'm having an issue trying to pin an object across multiple screen sizes.  The problem is that I'm hardcoding in the "duration" property of the pin, but the duration is set to pixels.  And since the pixels are different depending on what device you're using, it's causing issues.  Here's my current code:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

//Pen sticks to page (PATIENT-PAGE)
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 2300,
    offset: 0
})
.setPin(".patient-pen")
.addTo(controller);
```

Which is actually pretty simple to setup.  Now, what I'd REALLY like to do is something like this:

```
if(mobile == true) {
    var myDuration == 500;
} else {
    var myDuration == 2300;
}

new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: myDuration,
    offset: 0
})
.setPin(".patient-pen")
.addTo(controller);
```

Is this possible with this plugin?  Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm not seeing anything in the Docs about it.

Comment: I suggest maybe here: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/responsive_duration.html?

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and it seems to be working now.

```
(function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;
    console.log( width + ' : ' + height );

    if (width >= 768) {
    //Pen sticks to page (HCP-PAGE)
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        // duration: 2400,
        duration: 2400,
        offset: 0
    })
    .setPin(".pen")
    .addTo(controller);

    //Pen sticks to page (PATIENT-PAGE)
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 2300,
        offset: 0
    })
    .setPin(".patient-pen")
    .addTo(controller);
} else if (width < 768) {
        //Pen sticks to page (HCP-PAGE)
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        // duration: 2400,
        duration: 1250,
        offset: 0
    })
    .setPin(".pen")
    .addTo(controller);

    //Pen sticks to page (PATIENT-PAGE)
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 1250,
        offset: 0
    })
    .setPin(".patient-pen")
    .addTo(controller);

    }

}());
```

Comment: i'm looking for exactly something like this in my post but 
with three media queries.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028020/using-js-media-queries-to-change-scrollmagic-triggerhook-position